# How to implement event listeners for fast forward/rewind buttons in Android MediaController

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

Here is my custom media controller. I would like to add listeners for fast forward and rewind buttons. I am able to add listeners for previous/next videos. But not on these buttons. Can any one point out a reference or give an idea on how to implement it?

```
public class MediaController extends MediaController {

MyListener mListener;

public MediaController(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MediaController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MediaController(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
    super(context, useFastForward);
}

@Override
public void show(int timeout) {
    super.show(3000);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    super.hide();
}

public interface MyListener {
    public void onSetVisibilityCalled();
}

public void registerListener(MyListener myListener) {
    this.mListener = myListener;
}

public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
    super.setVisibility(visibility);
    if (mListener != null)
        mListener.onSetVisibilityCalled();
}

}
```

Listeners for prev/next buttons

```
    // Media control event listener
    MediaController.setPrevNextListeners(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println("forward button pressed");


        }
    }, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println("backward button pressed");


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way myself by adding custom `VideoView`. Added condition by overriding `seekTo()` method.

```
public interface SeekListener {
    void onSeekTo(boolean ffwdrwd);
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    boolean ffwdrwd = false;
    if (super.getCurrentPosition() <= pos)
        ffwdrwd = false;
    else
        ffwdrwd = true;
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onSeekTo(ffwdrwd);
    }
    super.seekTo(pos);
}
```

And in my activity,

```
videoView.setSeekListener(new SeekListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(boolean ffwdrwd) {
            if(ffwdrwd)
                //Movie Player - Seeking backward
            else
                //Movie Player - Seeking forward                
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the on click listeners for the default `MediaController`'s fast-forward or rewind buttons. The trickplay functionality is implemented naively using `seekTo`. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/MediaController.java). Search for `mFfwdListener`.

If you think about it, they have to let the user provide next/previous implementations (unless they were to implement the whole playlist, also). I guess they figure if you want something better than a naive implementation, you won't mind setting up a simple UI for it.

Comment: I have found a way. Check my answer.

Comment: You may have figured out something that meets your needs, but you did not figure out a way to do what you asked.